# why selenium gives duplicate element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

URL = https://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/beauty/ref=zg_bs_nav_0

```
products=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="a-section a-spacing-none aok-relative"]')

for pro in products:
            _rank=str(pro.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="zg-badge-text"]').text).replace("#", "")
            _link=pro.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="a-section a-spacing-none aok-relative"]/span/a[@class="a-link-normal"]').get_attribute('href')
```

I'm getting 50 same product value. How it's possible I don't know.
I Need Page all Product data. Why selenium gives only 1st element 50 times.

I'm using the latest version of Chrome drive and selenium.

My Output :

```
[['https://www.amazon.com/essence-Princess-Effect-Mascara-Cruelty/dp/B00T0C9XRK/ref=zg_bs_beauty_1/137-1053715-3426412?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=GVS76499NHPKKRPTDZTR', '1', 'Beauty & Personal Care'],
['https://www.amazon.com/essence-Princess-Effect-Mascara-Cruelty/dp/B00T0C9XRK/ref=zg_bs_beauty_1/137-1053715-3426412?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=GVS76499NHPKKRPTDZTR', '1', 'Beauty & Personal Care'],
['https://www.amazon.com/essence-Princess-Effect-Mascara-Cruelty/dp/B00T0C9XRK/ref=zg_bs_beauty_1/137-1053715-3426412?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=GVS76499NHPKKRPTDZTR', '1', 'Beauty & Personal Care']]
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal code to reproduce output](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I need the Products link and Rank. But I'm getting duplicate values=.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
products=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="a-section a-spacing-none aok-relative"]')

for pro in products:
            _rank=str(pro.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="zg-badge-text"]').text).replace("#", "")
            _link=pro.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class='aok-inline-block zg-item']/a[@class='a-link-normal']').get_attribute('href')
```

When searching by this locator `//span[@class="zg-badge-text"]` it brings first element matching this locator from the entire page.
But if you do it with `.//span[@class="zg-badge-text"]` it will bring first element matching this locator INSIDE the parent element `pro`.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578839/how-to-find-the-element-within-element-in-selenium) for more explanations.

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[@class="a-section a-spacing-none aok-relative"]/span/a[@class="a-link-normal"]"}`

Comment: Well, initially I just used your locators... But now I updated them so it should work correctly

Answer (score 1):

if I have to grab the product names, let's say. I would use the below xpath :

```
//li[@class='zg-item-immersion']/descendant::div[contains(@class, 'sc-truncated')]
```

and in code it'd be something like this :

```
for names in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, " //li[@class='zg-item-immersion']/descendant::div[contains(@class, 'sc-truncated')]"):
    print(names.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

PS : You are missing `]`as well in your `find_elements`

**Update1  :**

You can use the below `xpath` to get the anchor tag.

```
//li[@class='zg-item-immersion']/descendant::div[contains(@class, 'sc-truncated')]/..
```

Comment: I've to return the link and rank of that product.

Comment: `[[url1,Rank1],[url2,rank2]]` - example